# Llenar una tabla verticalmente con varias columnas usando DOMPDF

Tags: php, dompdf

Quier llenar una tabla de la siguiente manera en DOMPDF. Que tenga 4 columnas y que se vaya llendando por columna. En la primera fila de la primera columna se empieza colocando el nombre debajo goles y asistencia, y después se van colocando en cada fila sus goles y asistencia por temporada. Si ya no queda espacio en esa columna, se pasa a la siguiente. Y se sigue llenando, cuando se termine de llenar ese jugador, se pasa al siguiente jugador, justo debajo de donde quedo. Se coloca el nombre del futbolista 2 y goles asistencia, y se repasan los datos de ese jugador. Al estar llena las 4 columnas se pasa a la siguiente hoja. Así hasta terminar el proceso.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo, por si acaso no me explique bien ( Los datos no son reales solo los puse como ejemplo).

```
Pagina 1 ( Imaginense que tiene 4 columnas xD)
Nombre Futbolista    Temporada 9              12    12              
Goles Asistencia     Temporada 10             16    14                
  25     22          Temporada 11             22    21
  16     18          Temporada 12           Nombre Futbolista 3
  20     13          Nombre Futbolista 2      21    14
  30     12          Goles Asistencia         20    15
  15     18           16        14               .
  30     25           42        20               .
  44     16           30        15               .
  8      13           25        25               .
```